# "Some instances of this call cannot safely be inlined."

Tags: dafny

In Dafny, what does the error message "Some instances of this call cannot safely be inlined" mean?

I see it reported for calls to predicates inside asserts. E.g.

```
   assert LessThanOrEqual( [a[z]], a[z+1..r] ) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an informational message (not an error), and it's rather obscure! (I had to look it up myself to understand it.)

When there's a proof obligation that involves a predicate (here `LessThanOrEqual`), then the Dafny verifier internally sets things up so that if it can't prove the predicate, it will be able to tell you which conjunct inside the body of the predicate is failing. You will see this as "associated declaration" messages, which accompany error messages.

You can think of what's going on as, essentially, inlining the predicate's body into the call-site of the predicate. Sometimes, however, this cannot be done. For example, if the predicate is recursive, then there must be some limit to such inlining. If inlining cannot be done, all it means is that any error message you get will just say "can't prove `LessThanOrEqual(...)`", but it won't tell you which part of the definition of `LessThanOrEqual` it couldn't manage to prove.

A more subtle reason for why inlining cannot be done involves quantifiers. The verifier works with quantifiers through what are called *matching triggers*. A trigger informs the verifier when it would be a good idea to instantiate a quantifier. There are certain rules about what can and cannot be a trigger. The one rule that's relevant in your example is that arithmetic `+` cannot be part of a trigger. I'm guessing the definition of your `LessThanOrEqual` involves a quantifier, and that the verifier picks as a trigger of that quantifier a term that involves the second parameter to `LessThanOrEqual`. If the call above to `LessThanOrEqual` were inlined, then the `+` would sneak into the trigger, and that's not allowed by the rule.

Dafny thus chooses not to inline this call to `LessThanOrEqual`. All this means is that you'd get a slightly less precise error location if the verifier failed to prove the assertion. You probably wouldn't have noticed or been bothered about this; indeed, getting a less precise error message is probably less puzzling than the informational message you're getting instead.

There is a way suppress the informational message: if you pass in an equivalent expression that doesn't directly mention `+`. For example, you can you a local variable:

```
ghost var s := a[z+1..r];
assert LessThanOrEqual( [a[z]], s );
```

or a let expression:

```
assert var s := a[z+1..r]; LessThanOrEqual( [a[z]], s );
```

Rustan